# Userform on workbook open event and links that cannot be updated

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code on workbook open event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Myform.show vbmodeless
End Sub
```

If my workbook contains external links that cannot be updated, I receive a popup warning mentioning:

```
'This workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated'
```

The problem is that in this case the code in the userform does not initialise. I can see the form on the screen but the code within `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` is not executed.

I am assuming I need a solution to suppress this popup so that my userform code runs.

Answer (score 0):

The popup warning is displayed before any macro is loaded and ran.

You should do the `Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False` before opening the workbook. It is possible if the workbook is opened by another macro, otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I change `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` to `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` everything seems to work.

I wonder why.